# Is there a way to get around a PHP application that checks the domain it's on?

Tags: php, obfuscation, ioncube

I have acquired a PHP application that has a system class encoded with [Ion Cube PHP Encoder](http://www.ioncube.com/).

I copied the files and moved them to a new server, a development one. The first thing that got me was the application was to only work on the domain it was on, so obviously not from `localhost` or any other server.

I'm guessing somewhere in the encoded code is a string comparison from a hardcoded string to where the site is running from.

I'm not looking to do anything illegal or against the software license - just I want to do all the development on a different server, and then push the files back to the original domain.

Basically, minimise downtime for the production site.

Is there any tricks I can do? Can I stuff with my hosts file to do it?

Thanks

### Update

Forgot to mention that I have tried changing `$_SERVER` before the PHP checks. There is also a config file which asks for the URL. Leaving it on the old domain doesn't work, and changing it results in the invalid domain error.

Comment: have you tried `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']='www.example.com';` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='www.example.com';` before the script starts?

Comment: Surely this is something you should be taking up with the developers of the product. Assuming you paid them, I would think the intellectual property would belong to you. Otherwise, it's presumably up to them what your actual licence is.

Comment: Hosts file could work. Try pointing the domain the app was originally at to 127.0.0.1, make sure your web server will serve as that domain, and then check it in your browser... if the app works, at least you've verified that the domain check is what's breaking it. Maybe you can use a dummy subdomain and still have the real domain pointed at the right place.

Comment: @pax, many jurisdictions make certain kinds of reverse engineering legal.  See [Chilling Effects' FAQ](http://www.chillingeffects.org/reverse/faq.cgi#QID194).

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how exactly Ion Cube checks the host - if it uses hostname or equivalent then you would need to modify config on the server to think it has the same name as the production server, this is unlikely to be a good idea, but still maybe better than a developmestruction environment.

If it just checks the host HTTP header then you can just modify your hosts file back and forth

Answer (score 0):

what operating system are you using ?

add the domain name to your host file as 127.0.0.1 (localhost)

e.g: 
under linux

add this to file /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1  thedomainname.com
```

checkthis link to find other OS hosts file [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)

this should make the apps running on your localhost to refer to it's self

Comment: I have Windows 7 and OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: It's in /etc/hosts on OS X. Just make sure to edit it as root. Open a console and type `sudo pico /etc/hosts`. Hit ctrl+x when you're done in pico.